# Swift: Filter Array of Dictionary Using High Order Function

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

I have the following objects in an Array:

```
let john = ["name": "John", "Age" : "10", "Gender" : "Male", "City" : "SF"]
let peter = ["name" : "peter", "Age" : "12", "Gender" : "Male", "City" : "NY"]
let mary = ["name" : "mary", "Age" : "14", "Gender" : "Female", "City" : "TX"]
let bob = ["name" : "bob", "Age" : "10", "Gender": "Male" , "City" : "FL"]

var objArray = [john, john, peter, john, peter, mary, mary, bob, john, mary, peter, mary]
```

objArray consists of (4) john, (3) peter, (4) mary, (1) bob

If I can get a Array of Dictionary like below would be ideal:

```
[["qty": 4, "obj": john], 
 ["qty": 3, "obj": peter], 
 ["qty": 4, "obj": mary], 
 ["qty": 1, "obj": bob]]
```

What I have tried:

```
var copyOfObjArray = objArray
var newArray = [[:]]

for obj in objArray{    
    let name = obj["name"]
    let age = obj["age"]

    print(name)
    var i = 0

    for copiedObj in copyOfObjArray{
        if copiedObj["name"] == name && copiedObj["age"] == age {
            i++
        }
    }

    let newDict = ["qty" : i, "obj" : obj]
    //I am not sure how to remove all the objects that are similar
    let index = copyOfObjArray.indexesOf(obj)

    newArray.append(newDict)
}
```

Question: Is there a better way to accomplish this using high-order functions that makes it simple?  If so, code example would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for NSCountedSet. It's a one-liner:

```
let cs = NSCountedSet(array:objArray)
```

Now `cs` knows all there is to know. It is now trivial to form your result dictionary (but really, I don't see why you even need it; the NSCountedSet `cs` *itself* already holds the information):

```
let result = cs.map { ["qty": cs.countForObject($0), "obj": $0] }
```

Comment: `let results = cs.map { ["qty": cs.countForObject($0), "obj": $0] }`. A bit shorter :)

Comment: @Eendje I agree, I'll change it. But I still think he doesn't really even need the dictionary, since the NSCountedSet is holding the info - the objects and their counts.

Comment: This is beautiful!  Thank you.

Comment: Hi @matt my requirements changed.  Perhaps you know the answer to this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783399/swift-nscountedset-with-map