# Swift: NSCountedSet with Map

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9

I would prefer to use `Person` `Struct`, but I since it does not confirm to `AnyObject`, I can't use it with `NSCountedSet`

```
class Person: AnyObject {
    var name: String = ""
    var age: Int = 0
    var score: Int = 0
}


let personA = Person()
personA.name = "john"
let personB = Person()
personB.name = "larry"
let personC = Person()
personC.name = "jack"
let personD = Person()
personD.name = "bob"


var people:[AnyObject] = [personD, personC, personA, personB, personC, personA, personC, personD, personD]
let countedPeople = NSCountedSet(array: people)  //
```

I would like to assign the "score" property in each object to the count of each object from `NSCountedSet`

I am trying to do this with `Map`.  Code below does not compile.

```
let peopleWithUpdatedScore = countedPeople.map{( var person: Person) -> Person  in
     // I would like to assign the count of each Object as the persons score. 
    person.score = countForObject(person) 
    return person
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: cannot convert value of type 'Person -> Person' to expected argument type '(Element) -> _'
let peopleWithUpdatedScore = countedPeople.map{( var person: Person) -> Person  in
```

Question1: How can resolve the error and achieve what I am trying to do?

Question2: Can I use a `Struct` instead of the a `Person`'s `class`?

Answer (score 1):

Since `NSCountedSet` is not generic you'll need to cast the elements to `Person`.

```
let peopleWithUpdatedScore = countedPeople.map { (elm) -> Person in
    guard var person = elm as? Person else { fatalError() }
    person.score = countedPeople.countForObject(elm)
    return person
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way I can use Struct?

Comment: You will have to use a class because NSCountedSet is Cocoa / Objective-C and cannot see a Swift struct. http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_objective_c_objects_and_swift_objects

Comment: @user1107173: I think you should write your own version of `CountedSet` in Swift.

Comment: I would love to, but right now I need to push this feature out.  Perhaps I'll fiddle with this weekend.

Comment: Thanks @matt -- I have been a fan of your books for the past 3 years.  If I never need to understand something, I always refer to them!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help! I'm glad you are finding NSCountedSet useful.